# Node js logout instruction isn't running in a serial way

Tags: javascript, node.js, logout, passport-local

eI'm using:

- framework: express
- template engine :handlebars
- authentification: passport / passport-local

So login process goes well, but in logout i have a problem:

```
//routes/users.js
//logout 
router.get("/logout",(req,res)=>{
    req.logout();
    req.flash("success_msg","You are logged out");
    console.log(req.user);
    res.render("users/login");  
});


//views/users/login.js
{{user}} 

//app.js:
// Setting Global variables:
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    res.locals.success_msg = req.flash("success_msg");
    res.locals.error_msg = req.flash("error_msg");
    res.locals.error = req.flash("error");
    res.locals.user = req.user || null;
    next();
});
```

So the probleme is that when i clic on logout, i'm redirected to login view but the user object still there(not null),and when I refresh the user is initialised to null,

So my problem why the user haven't been set to null before refirection ?

Full files codes :(app.js, routes/users.js, /config/passport.js)

```
* app.js 

    const express = require('express');

    const methodOverride = require('method-override');
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const exphbs  = require('express-handlebars');
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    const flash = require('connect-flash'); 
    const session = require('express-session');
    //const path = require("path");

    const passport = require('passport');


    const app=express();

    // load routes :
    const ideas = require("./routes/ideas");
    const users = require("./routes/users");

    //---------------Mongoose Connect-----------------------

    //Map global promise = get rid of warning
    mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
    //Connect to mongoose
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/vidjot-db',{
        useMongoClient: true
    })
    .then(function(){
        console.log("MongoDB connected ...");
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

    //----------------Middlewares set in Use-----------------

    // Static folder Set:
    //app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));
    app.use(express.static('public'));

    // Session middleware :
    app.use(session({
      secret: 'mySecret',
      resave: true,
      saveUninitialized: true,
      //cookie: { secure: true }
    }));

    // passport middleware :
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());

    // handlebars middleware :
    app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({defaultLayout: 'main'}));
    app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

    // body parser middleware :
    // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    // parse application/json
    app.use(bodyParser.json());

    //methodOverride middleware:
    app.use(methodOverride('_method'));

    //Connect flash middleware:
    app.use(flash());

    //----------------My Own Middlewares-----------------

    // Setting Global variables:
    app.use(function(req,res,next){
        res.locals.success_msg = req.flash("success_msg");
        res.locals.error_msg = req.flash("error_msg");
        res.locals.error = req.flash("error");
        console.log("res.locals.user");
        res.locals.user = req.user || null;
        next();
    });

    /* app.use(function(req,res,next){
        console.log("3ale rou7i");
        console.log(Date.now());
        req.att_x="karim";
        next();
    }) */

    app.use(function(req,res,next){
        console.log("hani ne5dem");
        next();
    });

    //-----------------Routes-----------------------------

    // Index Route:
    app.get("/",(req,res) => {
        res.render('index');
        //console.log("get callback");
    });

    // about Route:
    app.get("/about",(req,res)=>{
        res.render("about",{title:"about1"});
    });

    // Use routes :
    app.use("/ideas",ideas);
    app.use("/users",users);

    //--------------------------------------------------

    //call local-strategy:
    require("./config/passport")(passport);

    //--------------------------------------------------

    const port=5000;

    app.listen(port,()=>{
        console.log(`server started on port ${port}`);
    });


* routes/users.js:


    const express = require("express");
    const mongoose = require("mongoose");
    const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
    const passport = require("passport");

    const router = express.Router();

    //--------------------------------------------------

    // Load User Model:
    require('../models/User');
    const User = mongoose.model('Users');

    //--------------------------------------------------
    //login form
    router.get("/login",(req,res)=>{
        res.render("users/login");
    });
    //handle login form:
    router.post('/login',
      passport.authenticate('local', {
        successRedirect: '/ideas',
        failureRedirect: '/users/login',
        failureFlash:true,
      })
    );
    //logout 
    router.get("/logout",(req,res)=>{
        req.logout();
        req.flash("success_msg","You are logged out");
        console.log("routes users",req.user);
        res.render("users/login");  
    });

    //register form
    router.get("/register",(req,res)=>{
        res.render("users/register");
    });
    // handle register form
    router.post("/register",(req,res)=>{
        let errors=[];
        if(req.body.password != req.body.password2)
            errors.push({"text":"password do not match"});

        if(req.body.password.length < 4)
            errors.push({"text":"password must be at least 8 characters"});

        if(errors.length > 0)
            res.render("users/register",{
                errors:errors,
                name:req.body.name,
                email:req.body.email,
            });
        else{
            User.findOne({email:req.body.email})
            .then(user=>{
                if(user){
                    req.flash("error_msg","email already registred");
                    res.render("/users/login");
                }else{
                    const newUser = new User({
                        name:req.body.name,
                        email:req.body.email,
                        password:req.body.password,
                        date:req.body.date,
                    });

                    bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, 10, function(err, hash) {
                        if (err) throw err;
                        newUser.password=hash;
                        newUser
                        .save()
                        .then(user=>{
                            req.flash("success_msg","You are registered, You can connect Now");
                            res.redirect("/users/login");           
                        }).catch(err=>{
                            console.log(err);
                            return;
                        });       
                    });             
                }
            })
        }

    });

    //--------------------------------------------------

    module.exports = router;


* config/passport.js :

    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
    const LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;
    const passport = require("passport");

    //-------------------------------------------------------

    // Load User Model:
    require('../models/User');
    const User = mongoose.model('Users');

    //-------------------------------------------------------

    module.exports=function(passport){

        passport.use(
        new LocalStrategy({usernameField:'email'},function(email, password, done){

            User.findOne({'email':email},function(err, user) {  
                if (err)
                    return done(err);
                if (!user)
                    return done(null, false,{message:"You are not registred"});
                if (!bcrypt.compareSync(password,user.password) ){
                    return done(null, false,{message:"Missing email or password !"});
                }
                return done(null, user);  
            });

        }));

        passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
            console.log("SERIALIZE");
            done(null, user.id);
        });

        passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
            console.log("DESERIALIZE");
            User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
            done(err, user);
          });
        }); 
    }
```

Comment: Why not just set `res.locals.user = null;` before you call `res.render()` in the `/lougout` route handler?

Comment: I try it ok it goes well but it isn't a good practise I think !
Second, I want to understand what is the matter to know how the execution works.
Thank's!

Comment: Well, `req.logout()` does not clear the `res.locals` that you already set in your middleware so somebody has to clear it before calling `res.render()`.  There's no mystery here.  You set `res.locals` in your middleware before the logout and didn't clear them before the render.

Comment: @user3524981 there are several grammatical errors in your question, can you please review as it makes the question a little confusing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have middleware that set `res.locals` based on a logged in user for every request.

Your `res.render()` template uses that `res.locals` data when rendering the page.

When you call `req.logout()`, nobody clears the `res.locals` that were already set when the user was still logged in so `res.locals.user` is now inaccurate.

So, when `res.render()` gets called after the logout, `res.locals` are still set as if the user is logged in and thus the page renders that way.

A simple solution is to clear the locals when you logout so they don't wrongly indicate the user is still logged in:

```
//routes/users.js
//logout 
router.get("/logout",(req,res)=>{
    req.logout();
    // clear user before rendering to indicate logged out
    res.locals.user = null;
    req.flash("success_msg","You are logged out");
    console.log(req.user);
    res.render("users/login");  
});
```

Comment: I think you for your collaboration, and i suggest to delete this post because apparently it will not be very helpful for developers do you think so ?